# console.log() vs console.clear() in Chrome Developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, google-chrome-devtools

How come `console.clear()` works by just typing `clear()` in the console but you can't do stuff like `log("Hello")` in the console?

You have to do `console.log("Hello")` to make it work. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

`clear` is defined by the console itself. Notice that the snip below fails. it isn't the same as `console.clear`.

```js
console.log(clear);
```